# Symfony2 Assetic base_urls within package - config for prod and dev

Tags: php, symfony, cdn, assetic

How can I use the same paths for local and cdn files, so that I can use the CDN for production and the local version of those files for dev?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

**config_dev.yml**

```
framework:
templating:
  packages:
    vendor_js:
      base_urls: "@MyProjectSiteBundle/Resources/public/js"
```

**config.yml**

```
framework:
templating:
  engines: ['twig']
  packages:
    vendor_js:
      base_urls:
        http: ['http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs']
        ssl: ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs']
```

Code speaks better than words:
**base.html.twig**

```
{% javascripts package="vendor_js"
'html5shiv/3.7/html5shiv.min.js'
'respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js' %}
```

I believe my concept is flawded, and I´ve failed to found a solution to this problem so far. Has anyone got experience with using relative paths so we can rely on CDN and local assets?

Comment: Interesting question. Did you manage to solve this? I haven't really tried it, but it might be possible to have a parameter set in your `parameters.yml` and then refer to it in your `base_urls` ?